# Python defining functions that create variables based on input name

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions

I have a function that takes a dataframe as input `pyth_wins(df)` and I want the name of the dataframe to create a new variable `total_DF` where 'DF' references the original input name how could this be done?

To use a concrete example, if the new variable was going to be `total_DF` where DF references the string of the input (name of that dataframe). This variable would equal a sum function applied to the dataframe after some manipulation. If I wanted to run `pyth_wins(2020)` it would create variable `total_2020` and if `pyth_wins(2021)`, `total_2021`. This would also be an output of the function, so reference able later on. Can a function return multiple outputs? I am thinking this would return a dataframe and then also create this variable that could be referenced in code. Thanks!

Comment: Dynamically creating variables is usually a bad idea. Better use a single dictionary and add the desired names as keys and the dataframes as values.

Comment: Hmm, basically I wanted to use the function to take an input, return a string and create a variable. First off, can that be done? Or can functions only return once... The next piece would have been creating the variable based on the function input (which is a name of a dataframe). How could you manipulate the name of the dataframe input as a string and use that throughout the function as part of what is returned?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not recommend to create variables like this but,

if you want to dynamically create variables based on some input list, and change the name you can try something similar to this

```
import sys

New_Variables = {
    "a" : 0,
    "b" : 1,
    "c" : 2,
}

def main():
    for (key,value) in New_Variables.items():
        vars(sys.modules[__name__])["Prefix_"+key] = value

    print(Prefix_a)
    print(Prefix_b)
    print(Prefix_c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```